# Define style for all labels

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm working in a c# application in winform.

I saw that there is no Style for element (unlike WPF). But is there a way to simply set all the labels to a specific design ?

Actually I do :

```
public partial class myControl : UserControl
{
    private Color LabelColor = Color.Indigo;
    private Color LabelFont = new System.Drawing.Font("Arial",
        18F,
        System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular,
        System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point,
        ((byte)(0)));

    public myControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        //Set design
        designLabels();
    }

    private void designLabels()
    {
        List<Label> labelsToStyle = new List<Label>();
        labelsToStyle.Add(labelName);
        labelsToStyle.Add(labelAge);
        labelsToStyle.Add(labelSize);

        foreach (Label l in labelsToStyle)
        {
            l.ForeColor = LabelColor;
            l.Font = LabelFont;
            l.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        }
    }
}
```

It works but it doesn't display correctly in designer (I have to run application to see my design). And maybe it exists a simplest way ?

Comment: You want to change the style of all labels at design time? what is wrong with your approach at run time?

Comment: in Visual Studio, on windows `myControl.cs[Design]` I cannot see my style. This style apply only when I run my application.

Comment: Best approach would be to create a custom control. simply derive from Label and in constructor set the properties the way you want and then simply use that label instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my comment the easiest is to create a custom control and use that one in your windows.

here how simple it is. Simply override the label and set in constructor the default value you want

```
public class DesignLabel : Label
    {
        public DesignLabel()
        {
            ForeColor = Color.Indigo;
            Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 18F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
        }
    }
```

then compile once and go to your design view, open your toolbox and you will see the "DesignLabel", simply drag drop on the window and that's it. If you change default in the class it will be changed all over the place.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the style already at design time so that you can see in in the Form.cs[design] you need to edit the Form.Designer.cs file! But this you have to do label for label by hand. I saved in this example the `Font` and `Color` in the project properties (sorry for the german version):

[image]

in my example I have 3 `Label`s. In the Form.Designer.cs file you can add the properties:

```
// label1
// 
this.label1.AutoSize = true;
this.label1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(12, 9);
this.label1.Name = "label1";
this.label1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(41, 15);
this.label1.TabIndex = 0;
this.label1.Text = "label1";
this.label1.Font = Properties.Settings.Default.LabelFont;
this.label1.ForeColor = Properties.Settings.Default.LabelColor;

// 
// label2
// 
this.label2.AutoSize = true;
this.label2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(12, 68);
this.label2.Name = "label2";
this.label2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(41, 15);
this.label2.TabIndex = 1;
this.label2.Text = "label2";

this.label2.Font = Properties.Settings.Default.LabelFont;
this.label2.ForeColor = Properties.Settings.Default.LabelColor;
// 
// label3
// 
this.label3.AutoSize = true;
this.label3.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(12, 122);
this.label3.Name = "label3";
this.label3.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(41, 15);
this.label3.TabIndex = 2;
this.label3.Text = "label3";

this.label3.Font = Properties.Settings.Default.LabelFont;
this.label3.ForeColor = Properties.Settings.Default.LabelColor;
```

The result looks like this:

[image]

**DISCLAIMER**

I would not recommend this approach! Editing the Form.Desginer.cs file is never a good idea! I would stick to the run time changes. If you want to change all `Label`s just filter the `this.Controls` for it and foreach through the collection like this:

```
this.Controls.OfType<Label>().ToList().ForEach(lbl =>
{
    lbl.Font = LabelFont;
    lbl.ForeColor = LabelColor;
    //lbl.Dock = DockStyle.Fill; // uncommented, because I could see only 1 Label
});
```

The result will be the same.