# How to make the label looks like this in windows form application

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to know how to create a windows label that looks like this:[image: How to get the line around the label]

I tried to find a tool from the toolbox to create a label looks like that.But couldn't found.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42654063/define-style-for-all-labels

Comment: It's called a `GroupBox`.

Comment: It's important to learn the terminology involved in the technologies you're going to use because it will improve your search results 1000-fold. This is a very basic term that has been used for decades.

Comment: The image shows a `GroupBox` containig two `RadioButtons`. A `Label` only displays text but does not take user inputs.

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the comments, that is a GroupBox with two RadioButtons in it:

[image]